# Angular - How to achieve dashed border for material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on material tables in angular 6 which requires a table with vertical border dashed and one line per cell , I tried with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmvlblexbdo), but no luck .

Please help me to achieve this. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply style on any column of the mat table. Use `/deep/ .mat-column-<column-def-name>` as selector.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efutct)

Add following styles to your CSS file.

```
/deep/ .mat-column-position {
    position: relative;
}

/deep/ .mat-column-position::after {
    content: " ";
    border - right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) @Pankaj Prakash , go the required.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure the exact look, but try this style. should get you started:

```
table /deep/ td:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Hi @bgraham, I tried with the same earlier , it will land up as a dotted border, but I need a single line per cell instead of a dashed series.

Comment: Changing it to 1px solid black should be the ticket then

Answer (score 0):

You can place border on the first .mat-cell.

```
.mat-cell:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```